# Troubleshooting iPad local network connectivity

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, troubleshooting, lan, ipad

Configuration:

- WiFi Router <-> Gateway PC (Ubuntu 11.10) <-> Internet
- iPad 2 (iOS 5.0.1) <-> WiFi
- MacBook Pro late 2007 (OS X 10.7.2) <-> WiFi

The WiFi uses static IP configuration, no DHCP.

I can ping iPad IP just fine from both Gateway and MacBook.
I can ssh (via iSSH) from iPad to the Gateway just fine.
I can ssh and otherwise ping from Gateway to MacBook just fine.

The problem: any connection (including SSH, telnet and trying to open something from Safari) from iPad to MacBook fails by timing out.

To do some debugging I need to be able to connect directly from iPad to my MacBook. Any clues how to troubleshoot my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Mac and iPad were connected to the same WiFi access point.

That WiFi access point was working in "Isolated AP mode", that prevented clients from seeing each other.

Doh.